# Storing a dynamic list using chrome.storage.sync.set() for a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to store an object, mapping a string to a list, using `chrome.sync.get`. My goal is to create a new list for a non-existing key or append an element to the list if the key exists. However, I am unable to populate the object. When I try to retrieve the values I have previously inserted, I get an empty Object as the returned value. Following is the code I am using:

```js
let currentTabId = '234';
let spawnedTabId = '390';

chrome.storage.sync.get(currentTabId, function(data) {
  if (typeof data.currentTabId === 'undefined') {
    chrome.storage.sync.set({currentTabId: [spawnedTabId]}, function() {
      console.log("Initialized "+currentTabId+" with "+spawnedTabId);
    });

    chrome.storage.sync.get(currentTabId, function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
  } else {
    data.currentTabId.push(spawnedTabId)
    chrome.storage.sync.set({currentTabId: data.currentTabId}, function() {
      console.log("Appended "+spawnedTabId+" to "+currentTabId);
    });
  }
});
```

The output I am getting is:

```js
>>> Initialized 234 with 390
>>> {}
       __proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code had three mistakes:

- incorrect use of a variable to make an object literal,
  instead of `{variable: value}` it should be `{[variable]: value}`, [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/how-to-use-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal)
- incorrect use of a variable to read a property from an object,
  instead of `obj.variable` it should be `obj[variable]`
- incorrect use of asynchronous API,
  the data should be read after it's written i.e. inside the callback.

```js
let key = '234';
let spawnedTabId = '390';

chrome.storage.sync.get(key, data => {
  const spawned = data[key] || [];
  spawned.push(spawnedTabId);
  chrome.storage.sync.set({ [key]: spawned }, () => {
    // now you can read the storage:
    // chrome.storage.sync.get(key, console.log);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Coming from Python, I assumed you could use variables as keys directly.